# MySQL User with select privileges can still update

Tags: mysql, sql, ssh, permissions, odbc

I have an OpenShift app with a MySQL database that I configured an ODBC connection for, such that users can use Access as a read only front end to the tables. I created such a user, but they are able to update data from the Access front end and it is reflected in the database. Here's what I did:

I created a user named 'reports', to be given read only access to only one schema, 'reviews'.

```
GRANT SELECT ON reviews.* TO reports@'%' IDENTIFIED BY `password`;
```

When I run

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'reports';
```

I get all N's and 0's. I understand there's no 'Y' for "Select_priv" because it's not a global select priv, only on one schema, so I figured it was okay.

When I run

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'reports'@'%';
```

I get

> GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'reports'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'stringstringstring'
>   GRANT SELECT ON 'reviews'.* TO 'reports'@'%';

Which I expected.

```
SELECT * FROM db where User = 'reports';
```

> |Host|Db     |User   |Select_priv|Insert_priv|Update_priv|...
>   |%   |reviews|reports|Y          |N          |N          |...

But when I go into Access, edit some data, then ssh into the database and view the database, the UPDATES are working.

I am using `rhc port-forward -a applicationname` before I connect in Access, and I use `rhc ssh applicationname` to view the MySQL from the server.

Comment: You may wish to see what other usernames are available on your mysqld. You may also wish to make sure your ODBC dsn is referring to the correct username. This is, I know from experience, surprisingly easy to get wrong. Connect your ODBC user, then do `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`.

Comment: My DSN was referring to the correct name, but Access was still (successfully) using the All Privileges admin account that I initially set up the Access DB with before I decided to switch to a read only account. It seems that once you give it a Data Source, you cannot switch it without creating a new Access DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in Access where if you feed it a Data Source, then try to change it, it won't actually let go of your initial Data Source even though it has appeared to. I had initially set my Access DB up with an All Privileges account, then changed the Data Source to a read only account, but it continued to use my All Access account behind the scenes. Deleting the Data Source using odbcad32.exe proved this, as I just got connection errors, even though it said I was connected via my valid Read Only account. I created a new Access DB using the Read Only data source from the beginning and it worked as expected.